# Warning window hierarchy when loading delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, warnings, hierarchy

Today I update my Xcode and started updating my app for the new iPhone 5 screen.

I suddenly notice that every time I go from Screen A to Screen B I get this warning:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

```
// This delegate method prepares the segue from Screen A (DilemmaViewController) to Screen B (OptionsViewController)
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Executes the following "if" statement if the user wants to add new options
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddOptions"]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        OptionsViewController *controller = (OptionsViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;

        // If the user has already put some inputs on the form we send them through the segue
        if ([edit count] > 0){            
            controller.edit = edit;
        }            
    }
}
```

I haven't touched this since the first version of my app so I'm not sure of what can be happening here.

I've looked around the web and some people talk about moving code from viewDidLoad to viewAppear but I don't think that applies to this scenario.

Comment: It could in fact have to do with viewDidLoad vs. viewDidAppear:animated, as when the view has loaded, it is not necessarily in the hierarchy *yet*.  Try moving your presentViewController code to viewWillAppear:animated and see what happens...

Comment: Hi, the prepareForSegue method is executed when you tap a button. I'm not calling from any of the viewDid methods or anywhere else manually. It is a "UIStoryboardSegue"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

My problem was that at some point I made the mistake of connecting the Touch Up Inside event on top of the original (and correct) segue event:

[image]

Now that I fixed it:

[image]

It's working correctly again.